# Savebox with \bgroup/\egroup doesn't work in beamer (for environment)

Tags: beamer, environments, boxes

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{document}
\savebox{\mybox}\bgroup This is a test.\egroup\usebox{\mybox}
\end{document}
```

But this fails (`Missing } inserted.` at the beginning of the environment and `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.` at the end):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\savebox{\mybox}\bgroup This is a test.\egroup\usebox{\mybox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note I want the `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, and not `{` and `}`, because I'm trying to create a savebox environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{foo}{%
  \savebox{\mybox}\bgroup%
}{%
  \egroup\fbox{\scalebox{0.1}{\usebox{\mybox}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
This is a test.
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

1. Why does it fail with beamer?
2. How can I make it work (note life's a whole lot easier for me if the `\begin{foo}`/`\end{foo}` can be within a `frame` environment, but currently it still fails wherever I move the `foo` environment, having removed the `usebox` of course)?

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to do something similar to this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47998/repeat-scaled-version-of-slide-savebox-and-usebox-in-multi-slide-frame ?

Comment: None of the commands `\mbox`, `\makebox`, `\fbox`, `\framebox`, `\sbox` and `\savebox` accepts the contents enclosed in `\bgroup` and `\egroup`. They are ultimately based on `\hbox`, but they gather their (mandatory) argument as normal macros.

Comment: @percusse Yes, I'm trying to do something similar to that, but automated (basically, I re-define the frame environment, and `\input{\jobname}`, to get a scaled version of some/all slides on a (few) slide(s)). See [my question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69991/5699) (we have agreed that the best was to copy the pdf and `\includegraphics` it, but I'm trying to do this without copying the pdf, just as a proof of concept since it's much more likely to break).

Comment: @egreg why does it work with `\documentclass{article}` then? Just curious.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron What do you mean? Of course `\documentclass\bgroup article\egroup` raises an error.

Comment: @egreg I mean that when I use `\documentclass{article}`, the `\newenvironment{foo}{\savebox{\mybox}\bgroup}{\egroup}` works, but if I use `\documentclass{beamer}` it fails when used (see my two MWE). If the problem is that `\savebox` doesn't accept content enclosed in `\bgroup` and `egroup` like you said, shouldn't it fail also in an article?

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron It doesn't actually work: try to use the box! If you load the `color` package, the accident 'working' (_i.e._ lack of error) is ended: you are seeing grouping in action!

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron The only one that "works" is `\mbox`, but  `\mbox\bgroup a\egroup` becomes `\leavevmode\hbox{\bgroup}a\egroup`, so it's only a coincidence that it makes a box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is environment `lrbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{foo}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
}{%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \fbox{\scalebox{.1}{\usebox{\mybox}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}This is a test.\end{lrbox}%
\usebox{\mybox}

\begin{foo}This is a test.\end{foo}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```